# @property not working after adding __slots__

Tags: python, properties, slots

How can I get **slots** to work with @property for the class below. I have several thousand instances of below class which is causing memory issues and so I added the slots

I created instances with data and then add location information later to the instances.

After adding **slots** my instance creation is not working and I am getting the following error

AttributeError: 'Host' object has no attribute '_location'

```
class Host(object):
    __slots__ = ['data', 'location']

    def __init__(self, data, location=''):
        self.data = data
        self.location = location

    @property
    def location(self):
        return self._location

    @location.setter
    def location(self, value):
        self._location = value.lower()

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.location == '':
            self.loc = 'Not Found'
        else:
            self.loc = self.location
        return 'Host(name={}, location={})'.format(self.name, self.loc)
```

Comment: Because you don't include the backing attribute `_location` in the `__slots__`. The error message tells you this.

Comment: Why are `_location` and `loc` not also in slots?

Comment: What is `self.name` supposed to be in the `__repr__`?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - sorry that was copy paste. name is with data which is a json

Comment: @zsh: so it is really `name = self.data['name']` perhaps?

Comment: yes and I use @property here for name as well. Does this have to be in the __slots__

Comment: Not if `name` is a property, no.

Answer (score 6):

`__slots__` works by creating descriptors on the class that have direct access to the in-memory data structure of your instance. You are masking the `location` descriptor with your `property` object, and you defined a *new* attribute `_location` than is not in the slots.

Make `_location` the slot (as that is the attribute you are actually storing):

```
class Host(object):
    __slots__ = ['data', '_location']
```

The `location` property (also a descriptor object) can then properly assign to `self._location`, an attribute backed by the slot descriptor.

Note that you do *not* need to use `self.loc` in the `__repr__`, just make that a local variable instead. You also are trying to use a `self.name` attribute which doesn't exist; it is not clear what value that is supposed to be however:

```
def __repr__(self):
    loc = self.location or 'Not Found'
    name = self.data['name']  # or some other expression
    return 'Host(name={}, location={})'.format(name, loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition for [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__slots__) should have the names of the underlying attributes that will store the data referenced by your properties. In the example below, [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Python) is invoked for variables that should not be accessed outside of the class. The code is similar to yours and has no errors according to the [PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com/) website.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    print(Host('Hello, world!', 'Earth'))
    print(Host('Hello, Xyz!'))


class Host:

    __slots__ = '__name', '__location'

    def __init__(self, name, location=''):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{!s}({!r}, {!r})'.format(
            type(self).__name__,
            self.name,
            self.location
        )

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value

    @property
    def location(self):
        return self.__location

    @location.setter
    def location(self, value):
        self.__location = value.casefold() if value else 'Not Found'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```